Chemfig - How to align a group of atoms vertically in a ring
\chemfig[atom sep = 3em]{ *6( -NH-(=O)-NH-(=O)-(-H_3C)= ) }

I have a problem with drawing thymine, where the NH group messes up with the ring (first image).
Is there a way to align the N and H vertically so that the ring is drawn correctly?
I tried the forced departure and arrival to the N atom, but that does not seem very clean to me (second image).
Thanks in advance.



Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig[atom sep=3em]{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)-NH-(=O)-(-H_3C)=)}
\end{document}



Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted.

I don't know why, but replacing NH with N{H} gives the desired output:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig[atom sep=3em]{*6(-N{H}-(=O)-NH-(=O)-(-H_3C)=)}
\end{document}



That's interesting, it should be useful also. Thanks!
